# Get the most common element of an Arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, apache-poi

I have an ArrayList from Type  `Cell`. The ArrayList has values from Cells of an Excelsheet.
I have tried different solutions from this site, but no one from them could was the right one.
Thats why i have no Code to show you what i did.
Almost every solution are for `String`.

I need to get the most common value in my ArrayList.

I tried to replace in the solutions the `Strings` with `cell.getNumericValue()` and change the Type of `Double` but it didnt worked.

Has anybody a solution for my problem?

```
Map<Cell, Long> f = dataaccx
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v, Collectors.counting()));
        Cell maxOccurence =
                Collections.max(f.entrySet(), Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();

        System.out.println(maxOccurence.getNumericCellValue());
```

Thats one Example what i tried. `dataaccx` is my Arraylist.

Comment: You don't have code because nobody gave you one? Do you think that's how to learn to code?

Comment: I edited it, i think i wrote it misunderstandable. I mean no solution worked for me. I tried to use the solutions here, but it didnt worked.

Comment: What do you propose should happen if the cell values have multiple different values of the same frequency of occurrence? I.e. the most common values are 3 and 4 and they appear an equal number of times.

Comment: @M.Gianota If there are more than one with the different value, than it should be print both values

Comment: @Unmitigated It print not the right Number. I checked it in my Excelsheet and it dont print the right number. I think it print the first duplicate but im am not sure

Answer (score 2):

You should group by the numeric value of the cell instead of the object itself.

```java
Map<Double, Long> f = cells
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cell::getNumericCellValue, Collectors.counting()));
Map.Entry maxOccurence =
        Collections.max(f.entrySet(), Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println(maxOccurence.getKey());
```

Comment: It cant find the method `getNumericvalue`  its a given Method of Apache POI. I didnt create it by myself.

Comment: @Nando94 What is the method name then? How do you extract the value from the cell?

Comment: Sorry its `getNumericCellValue` i think i wrote it wrong.

Comment: @Nando94 Change the method reference to `Cell::getNumericCellValue` in that case.

Comment: I did but it gives me not the right value. I dont know why, i checked it with the value of in my Excelsheet.

Comment: @Nando94 Can you provide a test case that doesn't work (i.e. a [mre])?

Comment: the Values what my Excelsheet shows me and the solution of you print, was different. It shows me the different value. I used the `MODE` in Excel to check it. But i checked it now manually and the value what your method print was right. I wondering that the Method in Excel shows me the not the most common value.  Maybe that was the reason i was confused. Thank you!

Comment: @Nando94 Happy to help.

Comment: @Nando94 If this solved your issue, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

If *multiple* most common values are possible and need to be printed, then it might be better to build the frequency map and find the maximal frequency in a single run using plain loop while building the map.

Stream API may be applied then to print the results.

```java
int max = 0;
Map<Double, Integer> freqMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Cell c : cells) {
    int freq = freqMap.merge(c.getNumericCellValue(), 1, Integer::sum);
    if (freq > max) {
        max = freq;
    }
}
final int maxFreq = max; // max is not final and cannot be used in lambda below
freqMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == maxFreq)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```